# aggressive caching by Ie8

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-8

IE8 is caching a lot of data. My application is working fine in other browsers.
IE8 even cache data which are submitted using post method.
I try to append a random number in url, set no cache header in pages but all in vain. I am so frustrated by this issue. I am not using ajax. This is normal web application using spring mvc. can anyone please give suggestion to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Adding a random number to the URL should fix the problem. It always worked for me. Are you sure that the problem is because of caching? Does clearing cache end up fixing the problem?

Comment: @user487473 can you elaborate on what that involves? I've tried deleting the cache from inside the web dev tools, from within internet options, closing the browser, etc… No dice.